# ¿Cómo alternar los efectos slideUp y slideDown con onmouseover y onmouseleave?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy teniendo un problema con el efecto de mostrar y ocultar una secuencia de productos pertenecientes a una categoría.

Mi objetivo es el siguiente:

1) Al pasar el cursor sobre una categoría deben mostrarse una serie de imágenes con efecto de `slideDown`.

2) Si el cursor no sobrevuela ninguna otra categoría, entonces las imágenes seguirán visibles, y se solo se recogerán con un efecto de `slideUp` cuando el cursor sobrevuele otra categoría.

3) Si el cursor permanece menos de 1 segundo sobre una categoría, el efecto de `slideDown` debe anularse.

4) Al pasar el cursor rápido sobre todas las categorías, solo las imágenes de la última categoría se visualizarán.

Yo he implementado ya el contador de tiempo para impedir el efecto de `slideDown` en caso de que la permanencia del cursor sobre la categoría sea menor a un 1 segundo, pero no logro integrarlo bien ni tener el efecto general que deseo.

Aquí les comparto la url del sitio: http://3.1.aquapure.fr/fr/

Trabajo en la sección “Nos Univers”, que posee 5 categorías, asociadas cada una de ellas a una serie de productos.

Muchísimas gracias por su tiempo y por su ayuda!

He aquí mi código:

`/*
 * Customize universe slider on homepage
 */
DOM = {
    onmouseoverClass: 'nav-item ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-state-hover',
    onmouseoutClass: 'nav-item ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active',
    timeEffect: 600,
    timer: null,
    all_li: function () { return document.querySelectorAll('.ui-tabs-nav .nav-item'); },
    all_liLinks: function () { return document.querySelectorAll('.ui-tabs-nav .nav-item a.ui-tabs-anchor'); },
    all_tabs: function () { return document.querySelectorAll('.content-15 .tab_home.ui-tabs .tab-content .tab-pane'); },
    container: function () { return document.querySelector('main .content-15'); },
    tabContent: function () { return document.querySelector('.content-15 .tab_home .tab-content'); },
    tabsParent: function () { let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('id', 'tabs');
        return div; },

    // Initialize when DOM is loaded
    init: function () {
        DOM.tabContent().style.minHeight = '478px';
        slideUp('class', this.tabContent().className);

        sessionStorage.setItem('li', 'empty');

        // Include tabs in #tabs container
        let output = '';
        this.all_tabs().forEach((tab) => {
            output += tab.outerHTML;
            tab.remove();
        });
        document.getElementById('tabs').innerHTML = output;

        // Redirect to shops when clicking on li elements
        this.all_liLinks().forEach((li) => {
            let hostName;
            li.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            li.style.transition = 'all';

            // Create url to be redirected on click on li elements
            li.childNodes.forEach((child, i) => {
                if (child.nodeName === 'DIV' && child.className === 'title_tab') {
                    hostName = li.childNodes[i].textContent.toLowerCase();
                    li.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                        let url = window.location.href = 'http://' + hostName + '.fr';
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
};


// Initializing when DOM is loaded
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
    var timer;

    hideInactiveLi();
    DOM.init();
    DOM.all_li().forEach(li => {
        li.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOver, {capture: true, once: false}); // once: remove event
        li.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseLeave, {capture: true, once: false});
    });
});

// Show products of current category on mouse on
const mouseOver = (event) => {
    if (event.currentTarget.className === DOM.onmouseoverClass) {
        DOM.timer = Date.now();

        if (sessionStorage.getItem('li') === 'empty') {
            sessionStorage.setItem('li', event.currentTarget.getAttribute('aria-controls'));
        }
        event.stopPropagation();

        slideDown('class', DOM.tabContent().className);
        hideInactiveLi(); // Hide all inactive li
        displayAndShowActiveLi(event.currentTarget);
        hideInactiveTabs(); // Hide all inactive tabs

        // Get current tab and display it
        let currentTab = document.getElementById(event.currentTarget.getAttribute('aria-controls'));

        slideUp('id', DOM.tabsParent().id);
        displayAndShowActiveTab(currentTab);
        slideDown('id', DOM.tabsParent().id);
    }
};

const mouseLeave = (event) => {
    var precedentLi;
    DOM.timer = Date.now() - DOM.timer;
    if (parseFloat(DOM.timer / 1000) < 1) {
        console.log(event.currentTarget);
        event.stopPropagation();

        precedentLi = document.querySelector('li[aria-controls=' + sessionStorage.getItem('li') + ']');
        console.log(parseFloat(DOM.timer / 1000));
        precedentLi.classList.remove('ui-tabs-active', 'ui-state-active');
        precedentLi.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1');
        precedentLi.setAttribute('aria-selected', false);
        precedentLi.children[0].classList.remove('active');
        document.getElementById(sessionStorage.getItem('li')).style.display = 'none';
        DOM.tabsParent().style.display = 'none';
    }
    DOM.timer = null;
    sessionStorage.setItem('li', 'empty');
};

function slideDown (selector, value) {
    if (selector === 'id') {
        $('#' + value).slideDown(DOM.timeEffect);
    } else if (selector === 'class') {
        $('.' + value).slideDown(DOM.timeEffect);
    } else {
        $(value).slideDown(DOM.timeEffect);
    }
}

function slideUp (selector, value) {
    if (selector === 'id') {
        $('#' + value).slideUp(DOM.timeEffect);
    } else if (selector === 'class') {
        $('.' + value).slideUp(DOM.timeEffect);
    } else {
        $(value).slideUp(DOM.timeEffect);
    }
}

// Hide all products of inactive categories
const hideInactiveLi = () => {
    removeOrSetAttribute(DOM.all_li(), 'class', null,'ui-tabs-active', 'ui-state-active');
    removeOrSetAttribute(DOM.all_li(), 'aria-selected', null, 'false');
    removeOrSetAttribute(DOM.all_li(), 'tabindex', null, -1);
    removeOrSetAttribute(DOM.all_liLinks(), 'class', null,'active');
};

// Show all products od current category
const displayAndShowActiveLi = (element) => {
    let li = element;
    li.classList.add('ui-tabs-active', 'ui-state-active');
    li.childNodes[1].classList.add('active');
    li.setAttribute('aria-selected', true);
    li.setAttribute('tabindex', 0);
};

// Hide all inactive tabs
const hideInactiveTabs = () => {
    removeOrSetAttribute(DOM.all_tabs(), 'aria-expanded', null, false);
    removeOrSetAttribute(DOM.all_tabs(), 'aria-hidden', null, true);
    DOM.all_tabs().forEach(tab => { tab.style.display = 'none'; });
};

// Display current tab
const displayAndShowActiveTab = (tab) => {
    // console.log(tab);
    tab.setAttribute('aria-expanded',true);
    tab.setAttribute('aria-hidden', false);
    tab.style.display = 'block';
};

// Setting existing attributes
const removeOrSetAttribute = (DOMarray, attr, property = null, ...values) => {
    DOMarray.forEach((el) => {
        values.forEach((value) => {
            if (attr === 'class') {
                el.classList.remove(value);
            } else if (property === 'display') {
                el.style.display = value;
            } else {
                el.setAttribute(attr, value);
            }
        });
    });
};`

Comment: Porque has querido hacer un `mouseover` en vez de un `mouseenter`? La información carga antes de que acaba el `slideUp` te recomiendo utilizar el `callback` del propio `slideUp` para controlar cuando se pone la información y cuando ejecuta el evento de `slideDown`. Uno de los problemas principales de las animaciones de JQuery (que no pasa por ejemplo en CSS) es que si ejecutas el evento otra vez sin que haya acabado la animación se realizará otra vez, esto te recomiendo controlarlo por atributos para detectar si hay una animación en marcha (Esto también lo controlas en el `callback`)

Comment: Realmente tampoco necesitas el `mouseleave` ya que como has dicho "Si el cursor no sobrevuela ninguna otra categoría, entonces..." solo tienes que controlar el evento de `mouseenter`. Cuando entra detecta si el que has entrado es el mismo. Si no es el mismo hace un `slideUp` al actual y *cuando termina* hace un `slideDown` al que has seleccionado. Ahí también detectas si el atributo (ejemplo) `animacion="subir"` no realizas de nuevo un `slideUp`. Cuando termine el slideUp cambias el atributo a `animacion="bajar"`, de esa forma no se "apilarán" los eventos de forma que suba y baje continuamente